# Virtual Address Space of a Process with PAE Enabled

Tags: memory-management, x86, kernel

I have a 32 bit Intel processor with PAE enabled.

Address Bus -> 36 bit(PAE Enabled)

Data Bus -> 32 bit

What is the range of virtual address space of a process in this system(either windows or linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 32-bit CPU, virtual address pointers are 32-bits. So each virtual address space (typically one per process on a modern OS) has a range of 4GB. PAE only affects the way physical memory is handled, it has no effect on virtual addresses.

A single process can have mapped into virtual memory at most 4GB at any one time. Typically, 32-bit OSes restrict this to 3GB or 2GB because they use some of the address space for kernel mappings.

Comment: Thanks David for the answer.

The below link tells that application can access above 4GB data through Application Windowing. Can you give me some clue on how it is done.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/hardware/gg487512.aspx

3. Application Windowing 
A PAE-enabled operating system can introduce an API to allow a properly coded application access to physical memory anywhere in the system, even though it may be above 4 GB. Ideally, the API to allocate "high" physical memory. This is highly advantageous for applications that require fast access to large amounts of data in memory.

Comment: Basically, you reserve one or more chunks of virtual address space somewhere in the 4GB. Then you allocate blocks of memory from the OS that can total more than 4GB. Then you tell the OS to map a particular block into a particular window in your virtual address space. In software, you map various chunks of memory into your address space as you need them. On Windows, it's called [AWE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).